# A company has 20 employees, 12 male and 8 female. How many ways are there to form a 5 person committee?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

***A company has 20 employees, 12 male and 8 female. How many ways are there to form a 5 person committee that contains at least one male and at least one female?***

Is this right?

no. of ways to select 5 out of 20 without any restriction = 20C5

no. of ways to select 5 male out of 12 , not any female = 12C5

no. of ways to select 5 female out of 8, not any male = 8C5

total number of ways when at least one male and one female = 20C5 - 12C5 - 8C5

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: okay.Thanks.Should i delete the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what the protocol is, maybe just leave it?

Comment: okay,will do :)

Comment: @techno I think your answer is ok.

Comment: @Stefanos okay :)